# How can i install my Lexmark X4530 into my ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, drivers, printing

i'm having problems installing my Lexmark X4530 into my computer running on ubuntu 12.04 i called lexmark tech support and also check on their website but there's no driver on available for the printer. is there any possibility that i can install my printer into my computer even lexmark said that there's no driver for this?

Answer (score 0):

Lexmark printers are not well supported for Linux.

According to [Lexmark](http://support.lexmark.com/index?pmv=print&page=content&locale=en&productCode=LEXMARK_Z645&segment=SUPPORT&actp=TOP_DOCS&userlocale=EN_US&id=RE108) Driver Support for Linux OS:  A Linux driver is not available for this printer.